# How to use custom DateTime format in U-SQL EXTRACT?

Tags: u-sql

Is it possible to provide a custom DateTime format string as part of the EXTRACT statement?  (The default seems to be mm/dd/yyyy, and my data is dd/mm/yyyy)

Or do we load the initial rowset as strings and then transform it them to DateTime

e.g. This seems to work (although local run times get much slower with > 1 input file)

```
@data =
    EXTRACT filepath string,
            username string,
            startsize long,
            endsize long,
            startdateSTR string,
            enddateSTR string,

    FROM @"/Input/Log_01_May_2016.txt" ,
         @"/Input/Log_02_May_2016.txt" ,
         @"/Input/Log_03_May_2016.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1);

@dated =
    SELECT filepath,
           username,
           startsize,
           endsize,
           DateTime.ParseExact(enddateSTR, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null).DayOfYear AS enddate
    FROM @data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have two options:

1. Extract as string and use DateTime.Parse methods in a subsequent select as you do. This is currently the preferred way.
2. Write a custom Extractor which is more aware of your cultural settings.

We are having more internationalization support for our extractors and outputters on the roadmap. Please [add your vote on our feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/15548004-please-add-culture-options-to-built-in-extractors) to help us with the prioritization.

Thanks!